# ServiceStack - Authentication for domain and subdomains

Tags: servicestack

I want to host the ServiceStack authentication providers on the root of a domain (domain.com) and have the authentication work for the entire domain (sub1.domain.com, sub2.domain.com).

Is it possible to replace the default implementation of `ICookies` with my own so I can set domain in the cookies?

I am seeing that `HttpResponseWrapper` instantiates the default implementation so I am guessing no.

Is there another approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I addressed my issue with the following [pull request](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/pull/375).

In Web.config, you can specify the domain for your cookies. ServiceStack was overwriting this value, but now ServiceStack will leave it alone if it is specified.

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <httpCookies domain=".domain.com" />
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Recent versions of service stack allow you to set a domain using the endpoint host config. endpointHostConfig.RestrictAllCookiesToDomain = "domain.com";