# Cross origin OAuth authentication with ServiceStack

Tags: ajax, oauth, servicestack

I would like to use my API website for authentication & authorisation of users and ideally keep my UI site purely static content (html, js, css). 
I have configured ServiceStack's OAuth & OpenId (and credential/basic) providers, so they answer to **api.mysite.com/auth/{provider}** requests

I would like to be able to users of **www.mysite.com** to be able to authenticate and then make calls to the API site via ajax.

The [BootstrapApi example project](https://github.com/ServiceStack/SocialBootstrapApi) - although very useful - demonstrates the API & website running on the same domain.

- Is this possible/secure with a static javascript client?
- Could I share a cookie between sub-domains?
- Could I return the access token to the client and have use it to calculate an Authorization header before each request?

Answer (score 2):

To address your questions -

- Is this possible/secure with a static javascript client? *Yes*
- Could I share a cookie between sub-domains? *Yes*
- Could I return the access token to the client and have use it to calculate an Authorization
  header before each request? *Sure but you may as well just use the
  built in auth cookie.*

It's just a matter of setting up your cookies on the top level domain, similar to what's shown @ [ServiceStack - Authentication for domain and subdomains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13829537/servicestack-authentication-for-domain-and-subdomains)