# JsonServiceClient not including session cookies in API requests for subdomain - ServiceStack

Tags: servicestack

Using the Typescript JsonServiceClient in an Angular app, the `ss-pid` cookie value keeps changing because JsonServiceClient is not including `ss-pid`, `ss-id` and `ss-opt` in requests to my APIs.

The subdomain I am using for my Angular app is `app.serverfoo`. The APIs reside at `serverfoo:5001`, `serverfoo:5002`.

The reason I am doing this is that I am working with my Angular app localhost and calling my 20+ APIs residing in development environment `serverfoo`, I ahve the following entry in my hosts file:

```
127.0.0.1        app.sdlxvh03
```

This allows my app to be run localhost, while I do development using ServiceStack sessions on my machine and still work with my APIs in the development environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cookies only apply to the domain that the request was served from. See this previous answer on how to configure domain cookies so they can apply to sub domains as well.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/23631061/85785